# I can't import stock data consistently in R

Tags: r, stock

Here are the codes that I use:

```
library(quantmod)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

# Start date: mdate => character
mdate <- "2015-10-30"

# End date: edate => character
edate <- "2016-01-07"

tickers <- c("VYM","WELL","WM","WMB","WMC","WRB","XLG","XLV","XPO","XRX","YUM","ZSL","AA","ACC","ACM","ACN","ADS","ADX","AEE","AEP","AFG","AI","AIG","AIT","AIV","AJG","ALEX","ALK","AMP","AMRC","AON","ASH","AXP","BDC","BDN","BHLB","BIG","BK","BOE","BRO","BTE","BTO","BYD",
             "CAH","CAPE","CBRE","CBU","CEE","CHK","CHT","CHU","CIA","CNI","COF","CPAC","CSD","CSL","CXO","CYH","CZA","DCI","DFS","DGZ","DHR","DLB","DNR","DPG","DRI","DRN","DSI","DTO","DTQ","DVA","EFC","EIX","EMR","EPD","EQL","ERJ","ERUS","ERX","ES","ETN","ETR","EUO",
             "EUSA","EW","EWI","EWT","EWZ","EZM","FDS","FENG","FFA","FIS","FLR","FMX","FPX","FVL","FXH","FXL","FXR","GAM","GDOT","GE","GEF","GF","GFI","GGB","GGG","GLW","GNRC","GPM","GRA","GS","HBM","HCA","HCI","HE","HLX","HQL","HSC","HUM","IAK","IBN","IDA","IGA","IGD",
             "IGM","IHF","IJH","IJJ","IJK","IRM","IT","ITOT","ITT","IVOG","IVOO","IWF","IWN","IWP","IWR","IWY","IXN","IYC","IYF","IYW","JCI","JJM","JKE","JKG","JKH","JKK","JNJ","JTA","KAI","KAR","KBE","KEY","KOP","KRG","L","LEG","LGI","LH","LLY","MDP","MDY","MDYV","MEI",
             "MFC","MGK","MLM","MN","MNR","MOS","MRO","MSCI","MSM","MTB","MTZ","NC","NE","NGVC","NIE","NMR","NTZ","NVS","ODC","OMI","OXY","PEG","PEI","PFS","PHI","PIN","PJP","PNR","PNW","POR","PPA","PSJ","PSX","RBS","RFP","RGI","ROK","ROP","RPG","RPM","RWJ","RWK","RYT",
             "RZG","RZV","SCHA","SCHM","SCS","SF","SFUN","SHW","SIG","SLB","SLYG","SLYV","SMM","SNE","SNN","SPHB","SPHQ","SSD","STAG","STN","STT","SYK","SZC","TFX","TRC","TSM","TSU","TTC","TY","UA","UAA","UBA","UFS","UGE","UMC","USA","USB","UTI","VAL","VB","VBK","VCR",
             "VFH","VGT","VIS","VLO","VMC","VOT","VUG","WAB","WBK","WFC","WHR","WMT","WNS","WRE","XLF","XLI","XLK","XLY","XOP","XSW","XTL","XYL","ZBH","AAN","AAP","AB","ABM","ACCO","AEO","AGN","AL","ALSN","AME","ANF","APH","APTV","ARC","AWI","AZN","BA","BAC","BAH","BAL",
             "BBD","BBW","BBY","BGY","BITA","BKD","BKE","BLX","BOIL","BVN","BXS","C","CALX","CATO","CE","CEO","CFR","CHA","CHS","CLB","CLR","CM","CMI","CNO","CO","CODI","CRI","CRK","CURE","CW","CZZ","DAC","DAL","DDM","DDS","DHI","DK","DKL","DKS","DRH","DY","DZZ","EBS",
             "EDU","EE","EGY","ELP","ENS","EOD","EPI","ESE","ESI","ETH","EV","EVC","EXP","FAS","FHN","FICO","FIX","FL","FLS","FNB","GBX","GCAP","GCO","GFF","GLL","GME","GNC","GNE","GPC","GWW","HBI","HEIa","HFC","HI","HIG","HJV","HNI","HNP","HOG","HOV","HPQ","HRC","HRL",
             "HTH","IIF","INCO","ITUB","IYG","JBL","JBN","JCP","JJC","JKJ","JNPR","JPM","JWN","KBR","KCE","KMF","KMT","KNL","KNX","KRE","KSS","KTP","KW","KWR","LAZ","LB","CMU","CXE","DBL","DJCI","DNP","DSM","E","ECON","EMLC","EWV","FMY","FUD","FXB","GEO","GSC","HYB",
             "HYMB","IBND","IGI","IVR","JPI","JRO","LTPZ","MAC","MEN","MRC","MYD","NIB","NLSN","NPV","NR","NXP","OIA","ORN","PAI","PFD","PFN","PFO","PKI","PMT","RJA","RNR","RZA","SAM","SCJ","SKT","SLV","STIP","TDTT","TEF","TIPZ","TMO","TOT","UNF","USL","VVR","VZ","WD",
             "WIP","EVRG","A","AGZ","ASEA","AXE","BLV","BOX","CTS","DAR","EC","EOG","ET","EWM","EWS","EXD","FAN","FLRN","FLY","FTI","FUN","FXA","GDO","HYS","HYT","IBA","IGT","K","KSA","KT","LIT","LQD","MHN","MIC","MINT","MIY","MNE","MSA","NUW","NWN","NXR","OMC","PAA",
             "PAC","PCY","PGF","PRGO","PSP","RBC","RSG","RWT","SAN","SEM","SOR","SPG","SRF","TBX","TCP","TNK","VCV","XLE","XME","ASR","CNA","CSU","CVA","DHF","DHS","DHX","DVYE","DZK","ECNS","EPHE","EPP","EWG","FCX","FE","FXN","GAL","GTY","GXF","HIW","HMN","HTA","IDT",
             "INN","JLL","JMP","KSU","MAA","MGA","MMC","NYT","OXM","PAG","PHG","PIM","PKG","PPG","PPL","PST","RNP","SAP","SCHE","SJR","SPE","STON","SXT","TDS","TEI","TEX","TTT","UDR","VDC","WEC","WU","CNC","DIA","EGP","EPS","FBC","FCF","FDN","FFG","FIF","FLT","FXD","GDV",
             "GGT","GIB","GPK","HEDJ","HT","IAI","IAT","IDE","IHD","IHE","IVW","IVZ","IWB","IWL","JDD","JKL","KFY","LM","LNN","LRN","MDYG","MET","MGU","MTOR","MTW","NBHC","NHF","NLS","NOA","NOC","NOV","NX","ORI","OSK","PBD")


dlist <- vector("list", length(unique(tickers)))

# Use quatmod api to retrieve stock data from yahoo finance, dlist => list of xts objects
dlist <- lapply(seq_along(unique(tickers)), function(i){
  res <- NULL
  try_var <- try(getSymbols(tickers[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE))
  if(inherits(try_var, "try-error")) {
    i <- i + 1
  } else{
    res <- getSymbols(tickers[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE)   
  }
  return(res)
}
)
```

The problem is that sometimes I can get data for 500 tickers, but sometimes 200. When I try to import small number of tickers, there is no problem importing data. 
What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe write a testing loop, if it fails you split the date further, and further until you hit the api with less than 500 requests on any single request, keep in mind that this will can generate a ton of call until you reach a sweat spot, and this could hit you call limit on the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TTR and some csv files from the nasdaq website we can find if the ticker is a valid ticker (only considers some markets) this will work to mitigate against an infinite while loop, which we will wrap around the original iterative API query code:

```
# Install pacakges if they are not already installed: necessary_packages => character vector
necessary_packages <- c("quantmod", "TTR")

# Create a vector containing the names of any packages needing installation:
# new_pacakges => character vector
new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]

# If the vector has more than 0 values, install the new pacakges
# (and their) associated dependencies: varied => stdout
if(length(new_packages) > 0){install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)}

# Initialise the packages in the session: bool => stdout
lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

# Start date: mdate => character
mdate <- "2015-10-30"

# End date: edate => character
edate <- "2016-01-07"

# store character vectors of all tickers to query: tickers => character vector
tickers <- c("VYM","WELL","WM","WMB","WMC","WRB","XLG","XLV","XPO","XRX","YUM","ZSL","AA","ACC","ACM","ACN","ADS","ADX","AEE","AEP","AFG","AI","AIG","AIT","AIV","AJG","ALEX","ALK","AMP","AMRC","AON","ASH","AXP","BDC","BDN","BHLB","BIG","BK","BOE","BRO","BTE","BTO","BYD",
             "CAH","CAPE","CBRE","CBU","CEE","CHK","CHT","CHU","CIA","CNI","COF","CPAC","CSD","CSL","CXO","CYH","CZA","DCI","DFS","DGZ","DHR","DLB","DNR","DPG","DRI","DRN","DSI","DTO","DTQ","DVA","EFC","EIX","EMR","EPD","EQL","ERJ","ERUS","ERX","ES","ETN","ETR","EUO",
             "EUSA","EW","EWI","EWT","EWZ","EZM","FDS","FENG","FFA","FIS","FLR","FMX","FPX","FVL","FXH","FXL","FXR","GAM","GDOT","GE","GEF","GF","GFI","GGB","GGG","GLW","GNRC","GPM","GRA","GS","HBM","HCA","HCI","HE","HLX","HQL","HSC","HUM","IAK","IBN","IDA","IGA","IGD",
             "IGM","IHF","IJH","IJJ","IJK","IRM","IT","ITOT","ITT","IVOG","IVOO","IWF","IWN","IWP","IWR","IWY","IXN","IYC","IYF","IYW","JCI","JJM","JKE","JKG","JKH","JKK","JNJ","JTA","KAI","KAR","KBE","KEY","KOP","KRG","L","LEG","LGI","LH","LLY","MDP","MDY","MDYV","MEI",
             "MFC","MGK","MLM","MN","MNR","MOS","MRO","MSCI","MSM","MTB","MTZ","NC","NE","NGVC","NIE","NMR","NTZ","NVS","ODC","OMI","OXY","PEG","PEI","PFS","PHI","PIN","PJP","PNR","PNW","POR","PPA","PSJ","PSX","RBS","RFP","RGI","ROK","ROP","RPG","RPM","RWJ","RWK","RYT",
             "RZG","RZV","SCHA","SCHM","SCS","SF","SFUN","SHW","SIG","SLB","SLYG","SLYV","SMM","SNE","SNN","SPHB","SPHQ","SSD","STAG","STN","STT","SYK","SZC","TFX","TRC","TSM","TSU","TTC","TY","UA","UAA","UBA","UFS","UGE","UMC","USA","USB","UTI","VAL","VB","VBK","VCR",
             "VFH","VGT","VIS","VLO","VMC","VOT","VUG","WAB","WBK","WFC","WHR","WMT","WNS","WRE","XLF","XLI","XLK","XLY","XOP","XSW","XTL","XYL","ZBH","AAN","AAP","AB","ABM","ACCO","AEO","AGN","AL","ALSN","AME","ANF","APH","APTV","ARC","AWI","AZN","BA","BAC","BAH","BAL",
             "BBD","BBW","BBY","BGY","BITA","BKD","BKE","BLX","BOIL","BVN","BXS","C","CALX","CATO","CE","CEO","CFR","CHA","CHS","CLB","CLR","CM","CMI","CNO","CO","CODI","CRI","CRK","CURE","CW","CZZ","DAC","DAL","DDM","DDS","DHI","DK","DKL","DKS","DRH","DY","DZZ","EBS",
             "EDU","EE","EGY","ELP","ENS","EOD","EPI","ESE","ESI","ETH","EV","EVC","EXP","FAS","FHN","FICO","FIX","FL","FLS","FNB","GBX","GCAP","GCO","GFF","GLL","GME","GNC","GNE","GPC","GWW","HBI","HEIa","HFC","HI","HIG","HJV","HNI","HNP","HOG","HOV","HPQ","HRC","HRL",
             "HTH","IIF","INCO","ITUB","IYG","JBL","JBN","JCP","JJC","JKJ","JNPR","JPM","JWN","KBR","KCE","KMF","KMT","KNL","KNX","KRE","KSS","KTP","KW","KWR","LAZ","LB","CMU","CXE","DBL","DJCI","DNP","DSM","E","ECON","EMLC","EWV","FMY","FUD","FXB","GEO","GSC","HYB",
             "HYMB","IBND","IGI","IVR","JPI","JRO","LTPZ","MAC","MEN","MRC","MYD","NIB","NLSN","NPV","NR","NXP","OIA","ORN","PAI","PFD","PFN","PFO","PKI","PMT","RJA","RNR","RZA","SAM","SCJ","SKT","SLV","STIP","TDTT","TEF","TIPZ","TMO","TOT","UNF","USL","VVR","VZ","WD",
             "WIP","EVRG","A","AGZ","ASEA","AXE","BLV","BOX","CTS","DAR","EC","EOG","ET","EWM","EWS","EXD","FAN","FLRN","FLY","FTI","FUN","FXA","GDO","HYS","HYT","IBA","IGT","K","KSA","KT","LIT","LQD","MHN","MIC","MINT","MIY","MNE","MSA","NUW","NWN","NXR","OMC","PAA",
             "PAC","PCY","PGF","PRGO","PSP","RBC","RSG","RWT","SAN","SEM","SOR","SPG","SRF","TBX","TCP","TNK","VCV","XLE","XME","ASR","CNA","CSU","CVA","DHF","DHS","DHX","DVYE","DZK","ECNS","EPHE","EPP","EWG","FCX","FE","FXN","GAL","GTY","GXF","HIW","HMN","HTA","IDT",
             "INN","JLL","JMP","KSU","MAA","MGA","MMC","NYT","OXM","PAG","PHG","PIM","PKG","PPG","PPL","PST","RNP","SAP","SCHE","SJR","SPE","STON","SXT","TDS","TEI","TEX","TTT","UDR","VDC","WEC","WU","CNC","DIA","EGP","EPS","FBC","FCF","FDN","FFG","FIF","FLT","FXD","GDV",
             "GGT","GIB","GPK","HEDJ","HT","IAI","IAT","IDE","IHD","IHE","IVW","IVZ","IWB","IWL","JDD","JKL","KFY","LM","LNN","LRN","MDYG","MET","MGU","MTOR","MTW","NBHC","NHF","NLS","NOA","NOC","NOV","NX","ORI","OSK","PBD")

# URLs containing tickers for different exchanges: 
urls <- c("https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download", 
          "https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=amex&render=download", 
          "https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download")

# Function to retrieve tickers from nasdaq.com: ticker_retriever => function: 
# Parameter character vector or urls, Returned object character vector of tickers
ticker_retriever <- function(urls){ 
      unique(unlist(lapply(seq_along(urls), function(i){
        as.character(read.csv(urls[i])[,c("Symbol"), drop = TRUE])
        }
      )
    )
  )
}


# Store unique and valid tickers: valid_tickers => character vector: 
stock_symbols <- unique(c(as.character(stockSymbols()$Symbol), ticker_retriever(urls)))

# Store unique ticker values from the ticker vector: unique_tickers => character vector
unique_tickers <- unique(tickers)

# Subset the unique_tickers to only contain those tickers also present 
# in the stock_symbols vector: valid_tickers => character vector 
valid_tickers <- unique_tickers[unique_tickers %in% stock_symbols]

# Copy the valid_tickers vector to iterate through in the loop:
# valid_tickers => character vector: 
current_tickers <- valid_tickers

# Create an empty list to store xts objects: dlist => list 
dlist <- setNames(vector("list", length(valid_tickers)), valid_tickers)

# POSIXct scalar used in calc to break the loop if run over time: start_time => POSIXct
start_time <- Sys.time() 

# POSIXct scalar used to break the loop if run over time
run_time <- as.numeric(0)

# Use quatmod API to defensively retrieve stock data from Yahoo Finance, dlist => list of xts objects
while(length(current_tickers) > 0 || run_time <= 10){ 
  # Subset out the tickers we have data for: current_tickers => character vector
  current_tickers <- current_tickers[sapply(dlist[current_tickers], is.null)]
  # Store the yahoo-finance xts objects into the list elements still requiring data: 
  # dlist => list of xts objects
  dlist[current_tickers] <- lapply(seq_along(current_tickers), function(i){
    # Reset res object to the default value NULL: res => NULL object
    res <- NULL
    # Try to retrieve OHLCAV values from Yahoo finance for date range: try_var => try object
    try_var <- try(getSymbols(current_tickers[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE))
    # If there is an error retrieving the data increment the iterator i by 1: i integer scalar
    if(inherits(try_var, "try-error")) {
      i <- i + 1
      # Otherwise retrieve the xts object for the current ticker: res => xts
    } else{
      res <- getSymbols(current_tickers[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE)
    }
    # POSIXct scalar used in calc to break the loop if run over time: end_time => POSIXct 
    end_time <- Sys.time() 
    # Loop breaking object: 
    run_time <- as.numeric(difftime(end_time, start_time, units = "mins"))
    # Return res object and store it in the list: Res => dlist list of xts objects 
    return(res)
    }
  )
}

# Column bind all xts objects in the list: data => xts
data <- do.call("cbind", dlist)



 # Transpose data.frame: td_data => data.frame
td_data <- within(data.frame(price_var = row.names(t(data)), t(data), row.names = NULL), 
                  {
                    ticker_cd <- as.factor(gsub("[.].*", "", gsub("[.]\\d$", "", price_var)))
                    price_var <- as.factor(gsub(".*[.]", "", gsub("[.]\\d$", "", price_var))) 
                  }
)

# Re-order vectors; keep complete cases: td_data_o => data.frame
td_data_o <- td_data[complete.cases(td_data), 
                     c(names(td_data)[sapply(td_data, is.factor)],  
                       names(td_data)[sapply(td_data, function(x){!is.factor(x)})])]

# Reshape: abc => data.frame
abc4 <- do.call("cbind", split(td_data_o, td_data_o$price_var))
```

Comment: Oh man.. I felt sorry to ask you again. Thank you so much. It would take long for testing. Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [1]   - I got this error. Did you get this as well? It is from "stock_symbols <- as.character(stockSymbols()$Symbol)"

Comment: @DongchulPark no worries man, I am trying to edit it so you will have a will loop that will continue until all tickers in the vector are no longer present.

Comment: @DongchulPark try above, hope it works for you, it is working on my machine, However you only have 460 valid tickers from your original 632.

Comment: Error in names(x) <- value : 'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [1] - I got this error. Didn't you get this as well? It is from "stock_symbols <- as.character(stockSymbols()$Symbol)"

Comment: OMG.. That's a lot of work!  It must be working in your machine, right? I got "> # Store unique and valid tickers: valid_tickers => character vector: 
> stock_symbols <- unique(c(as.character(stockSymbols()$Symbol), ticker_retriever(urls)))
Fetching AMEX symbols...
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [1]"  Even when I delete a URL for Amex, it is still there. Something's weird.

Comment: @DongchulPark restart your R session, then highlight all code and run it. It is working on my machine.

Comment: Hm.. No it doesn't. Does quantmod must be the latest version? I got warning massage that quantmod is activated from R 3.6.3. I restarted R for sure.

Comment: @DongchulPark strange. Try the above code again, have you installed TTR ?

Comment: If not change the line to this; `stock_symbols <- unique(c(ticker_retriever(urls)))`

Comment: Hey! it works! It was because I did not install packages. Sorry about that.

Comment: no worries mate, I used to be a pricing analyst and before that I was a tutor at university (including for a unit in quantitative analytics) so it was just as much for me brushing up my skills as for you haha !

Comment: You must be a good tutor. Thank you again man! You have a fantastic weekend!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some sleep time (say 3 seconds) every `n` number of tickers.

```
library(quantmod)

dlist <- lapply(seq_along(unique(tickers)), function(i){
    if(i %% 10 == 0)  Sys.sleep(3)
    try_var <- try(getSymbols(tickers[i],
                    from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE))
    if(inherits(try_var, "try-error")) {
       i <- i + 1
    } else{
      res <- getSymbols(tickers[i], 
                        from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE)   
    }
      return(res)
})
```

You can increase/decrease `n` from 10 to whatever number that suits you using trial and error.

Comment: Hey Ronak. Thank you always for the help. I got a tiny error, but it works!